# How can I pip install requirements.txt from multiple extra-index-url (private pypi)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi

I've 2 private package repositories hosted on 2 gitlab projects. I've used poetry export to create `requirements.txt` and the file contains detail for `--extra-index-url` for both repo. Now that requirements is to be installed on another fresh system using pip. But I cannot manage the deploy token for those repo. As pip doesn't uses from `.pypirc`. (As per another answer in stackoverflow).

How can I install / add my private pypi to pip?

P.S.: Sample index-url: `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{project_id}/packages/pypi/simple`